# What to call someone who comes from the same hometown?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What word or phrase can describe people who come from the same place?

> It's always nice to meet ______ in a foreign land

Comment: No research? What did you find and discard as unsuitable, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This phrase, perhaps?

**neck of the woods**

Per *Merriam-Webster*, it means:

> the place or area where someone lives

*He's from my neck of the woods.*

Although a bit clunky, you could say:

*It's always nice to meet someone/people from one's *neck of the woods* in a foreign land.*

Answer (score 5):

If you know the endonym of the town (the noun naming the person who comes from there), you can use fellow (endonym).

It's always nice to meet a fellow Torontonian/Parisian/Berliner in a foreign land.

In general, you can use fellow citizen.

Comment: I doubt *fellow citizen* would be preferred over the ancient and pedestrian *fellow countryman* — or even the fancier *fellow expat*.

Comment: I focussed on the hometown part, which wouldn't fit with countryman.

Answer (score 4):

That would be a *compatriot*.

> **compatriot**, *n.*
> **1.** One who is of the same country with another; a fellow-countryman.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](http://oed.com)</sub>

. . .

PS: Someone from your hometown *is* from your country. Nonetheless, the word is also used more broadly to indicate a fellow [city/state/locale]-person . . .

> One of her favorite singers was her hometown compatriot, James Lee.
> Lee came to Chicago as a teenager in the early 1930s and quickly
> aligned himself with emerging gospel singers Robert Anderson, Eugene
> Smith, and Theodore R. Frye.
>  <sub>[*The Golden Age of Gospel*
> by Horace Clarence Boyer,
> 2000](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Golden_Age_of_Gospel/EzZ7GjkQixkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=hometown+compatriot&pg=PA91&printsec=frontcover)</sub>
>
> Half a century after their days covering rock music, student
> demonstrations, flower children, and civil rights, Poppy said that he
> and George Leonard, his visionary California compatriot, would go to
> lunch near their office on Market Street in San Francisco and marvel
> at how “this was the best job we would ever have.”
>  <sub>[*Look —
> How a Highly Influential Magazine Helped Define Mid-Twentieth-Century
> America* by Andrew L. Yarrow,
> 2021](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Look/nitEEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22california+compatriot%22&pg=PP31&printsec=frontcover)</sub>
>
> Perhaps with the exception of her Boston compatriot Josephine St.
> Pierre Ruffin, editor of the *New Era*, a club magazine, her choice at
> this time was unprecedented.
>  <sub>[*Pauline E. Hopkins — A
> Literary Biography* by Hanna Wallinger,
> 2012](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pauline_E_Hopkins/tWECAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22boston+compatriot%22&pg=PA288&printsec=frontcover)</sub>
>
> Bob has been a Colorado mountain-town compatriot of mine for the past
> two decades, but through it all I have not been able to get him out of
> his mountain hermitage and onto the river.
>  <sub>[*The Monkey
> Wrench Dad* by Ken Wright,
> 2012](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Monkey_Wrench_Dad/Ip7pbHNBiukC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22town+compatriot%22&pg=PT43&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

Comment: Quoth Antony coming to bury Caesar not to praise him: *“Friends, Romans, **compatriots**, lend me your ears!”* :)

Comment: Countries often have more than one town.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 1):

You could call them **a(nother) hometown native,** i.e. someone else native to your hometown.

[Per Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/native), "native" in this sense can mean "one born or reared in a particular place" or "a person who has always lived in a place as distinguished from a visitor or a temporary resident."